# materialize side bar with responsive page content

Tags: javascript, css, html, material-design

I just got started with materialize

I have create side bar,which should remain open by default, and when clicked on menu button it should be able to display/hidden.

Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/5hrpcp1j/16/

Currently issue are:

1. Page content gets disabled when side bar opens on click on menu button
2. In menu, title, first line, second line text does not appear
3. some extra div content appears above copyright footer.

I appreciate if someone can help me to improve this appearance.

html:

```
<body>
    <main>
         <nav>
              <div class="nav-wrapper light-blue lighten-1">
                <ul id="nav-mobile" class="full side-nav">

                    <li><a href="sass.html">John Daglas</a>
                      <ul class="collection">
                        <li class="collection-item avatar">
                          <img src="http://globe-views.com/dcim/dreams/dog/dog-05.jpg" alt="" class="circle">
                          <span class="title">Title</span>
                          <p>First Line <br>
                             Second Line
                          </p>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                <li><a href="components.html">Components</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript.html">Javascript</a></li>
                </ul>

                <!-- Include this line below -->
                <a class="button-collapse" href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
                <!-- End -->

              </div>
        </nav>


    </main>
    <footer class="page-footer">
        <div class="footer-copyright">
            <div class="container">© 2014 Copyright Text <a class="grey-text text-lighten-4 right" href="#!">More Links</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: I noticed another issue, though I'm not sure if it's jsfiddle playing up: open the menu, open a new tab, go back to fiddle, click body to close menu .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer your questions:

1) This is the default behavior of the sidenav plugin.

2) The default color for the nav text is white. Set a `nav { color: #000 }` rule and it will work

3) You have to remove the padding of your footer `footer.page-footer { padding-top: 0px; }`

It's all CSS and devtools!

Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nzxd5r3r/1/)

Note: For your last comment, for some reason sometimes, it creates two overlays  and as a result removes only one. Check it in your environment for better debugging.

**Update:** I think the multiple overlays is a bug that haven't been fixed. Take a look a [this](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/pull/1865/files)

Comment: thanks a lot, but I am still want to achive 1, there are few websites where I saw that when side bar opens, the page content moves on right side and could be seen along with side bar. side bar can be openned/clossed without affecting page content. I mean something like http://preview.themebucket.net/?item=bucketadmin

Comment: This isn't how materialise sidenav works. Maybe you need to change your library or create it with custom code. This is an old but nice example from css tricks https://css-tricks.com/off-canvas-menu-with-css-target/